# How to render line breaks from JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to build a testimonial website with AngularJS 1.1.5 and PHP

I have an array of JSON objects consisting of Name, Message and Date.

The real testimonial will be the attribute Message and there will be line breaks in the testimonial.

```
[
{
    "Name": "Snow White",
    "Message": "Dear all, I need a new line <br> Is it possible to do it in AngularJS?",
    "Date": "16/11/2013"
},
{
    "Name": "Cinderalla",
    "Message": "Dear all, I need a new line <br> Is it possible to do it in AngularJS?",
    "Date": "10/11/2013"
},
{
    "Name": "Ariel",
    "Message": "Dear all, I need a new line <br> Is it possible to do it in AngularJS?",
    "Date": "20/06/2013"
}
]
```

After using $resource to get the array and link it to $scope.Ctestimonials, I used ng-repeat to render all the objects onto HTMl.

```
<div id="testimonialbody" ng-controller="TestimonialCtrl">
<ul class="testimonialul">
<li ng-repeat="testimonial in Ctestimonials" class="testimonialclass">
<blockquote> {{testimonial.Message}}
</blockquote>
<cite>{{testimonial.Name}}, {{testimonial.Date}}</cite>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However, I could not get the line breaks to render correctly in the html page. Does anyone know how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Look into ng-bind-html

Comment: @epascarello Thought of that but ain't that exposed to cross scripting attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As epascarello said, [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) handles this nicely.  I'm not sure where it stood in 1.1.5, but it uses the `$santize` service to handle escaping.  Per the docs, if `$santize` isn't available, it throws an exception rather than allowing an exploit.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify({{testimonial.Name}},null,'\t')
    .replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
    .replace(/\t/g,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

Comment: To be XHTML compatible use `<br />`.